# Vector of pairs - left hand side of operand of comma has no effect

Tags: c++

I declared a vector a pairs with:

```
vector <pair <int, int> > args;
```

Then I want to push a pair into the vector like this:

```
args.push_back((1,-1));
```

It tells me that the left-hand operand of comma has no effect.
Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Anything like plaster of paris?

Comment: You ruined a whole slew of jokes Cubbi!

Comment: It's OK. It's not the spring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say `args.push_back(std::make_pair(1,-1));`. Or any number of alternatives:

```
// #1
args.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(1,-1));

// #2
typedef std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > pvector;
pvector args;
args.push_back(pvector::value_type(1,-1));

// #3
typedef std::pair<int, int> intpair;
std::vector<intpair> args;
args.push_back(intpair(1,-1));

// #4
args.emplace_back(1, -1);  // sexy

//...
```

Comment: So what does `(1,-1)` actually mean? ;)

Comment: I thought if I might declare it `pair <int, int> t (1,-1)`, I might push it in the array throught the same method, thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @bmargulies: I know what it means, I was hinting that he added that explanation to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

(1, -1) is a syntax that means 'evaluate 1, evaluate -1, and then use -1 as the value'. It has nothing to do with making an instance of the pair. You have to use `std::make_pair(1,-1)` to make the pair that you push.